# How to select lines which have equal values in columns

Tags: r, database

I have a complete data frame of all cities from Brazil. I want just some predefined cities. I have a column with these predefined cities. Then I'd like to use all the columns from my data frame, but select only the lines which coincides the cities of column with all cities and the column with predefined cities.

```
data = read.csv(file="C:/Users/guilherme/Desktop/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
data
> AllCities Year1990 Year200 PredefinedCities
1         A        2       4                C
2         B        2       2                A
3         C        3       4                F
4         D        4       2                 
5         E        5       6                 
6         F        6       2
```

I want the following

```
> data
  AllCities Year1990 Year200 PredefinedCities
1         C        3       4                C
2         A        2       4                A
3         F        6       2                F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R base

Option 1

```
> data[data$AllCities %in% data$PredefinedCities, -ncol(data)]
      AllCities Year1990 Year200
    1         A        2       4
    3         C        3       4
    6         F        6       2
```

Option 2

```
> subset(data, AllCities %in% PredefinedCities, select = -PredefinedCities)
  AllCities Year1990 Year200
1         A        2       4
3         C        3       4
6         F        6       2
```

Note that column `PredefinedCities` in final data.frame will not remain in same order as in the original dataframe, so I skipped it

A dplyr approach:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data %>% 
    filter(AllCities %in% PredefinedCities) %>% 
    select(-PredefinedCities)
  AllCities Year1990 Year200
1         A        2       4
2         C        3       4
3         F        6       2
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(AllCities = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                       Year1990 = c(2L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
                       Year200 = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L),
                       PredefinedCities = c("C","A", "F", NA, NA, NA)), 
                  class = "data.frame", 
                  row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: There is some way to fix all the columns lines and change just the order of AllCities?